# Will edited comments reach addressees?

Tags: support, comments, questions, comment-replies

As we all know, if you want to make somebody aware of an response to a comment, you have to address them using `@username` if it's not their answer or question you're commenting in. (Sadly - Facebook style notification of all participants in a thread would be *way* better. But that's a different story.)

If you forget to do this, and edit your comment to add `@username` a short time later, will the user see the comment on their "recent" page? Or do you have to remove and rewrite the comment to trigger the notification?

Comment: Just test it. Answer me!

Comment: comment - added @John after that

Comment: Works! I was notified.

Comment: But what if I change at-John into @Something else instead?

Comment: And what if I include both @John and @S.Mark, and even @Arjan? (Without actually editing anything.)

Comment: Good questions! And just out of curiosity, how will the system deal with Umlauts? @Arjän, what do you think?

Comment: @Arjädüdilöda works, because only the first three letters behind the @ are evaluated.

Comment: If you have several @s, then the first one wins. @John is informed (well, never tried to inform myself before), @Arj does not work anymore, because he's second.

Comment: @Johñ, according to *a starts-with, case insensitive match of at least THREE characters to the displayname* at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/new-replies-notification/ you're probably right (and indeed I *normally* do get notifications for @Arj, and for @Arjanvan without spaces). However: no notifications for *any* of the above @'s yet. (But maybe I should be more patient.)

Comment: And are we sure that a too-short @s makes the notifications take the next, like @John hopes?

Comment: @Arj, no, that's not what I hoped. "@s" prevents further notification. My description with @John/@Arj was only an example without expecting that I get a notification.

Comment: @John: Because I like to talk to myself (I'm the only one understanding me), I try to notify myself. Let's have a look.

Comment: @John, now that I received my first notification for this very question, I suppose we can safely say: 1) Only the first @ is parsed, no matter how long it is and no matter if a match can be made; 2) If the matched @ refers to yourself, then no notification is triggered; 3) The match should be at least 3 characters, but if there's more characters they should match too (spaces ignored); 4) Umlauts et al will probably work, but only if they're in the display name; funny rewriting of display names will not trigger notifications.

Comment: @Arj: Confirmed!

Comment: Voted to close as dupe because the other question has a more current answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, they will reach the addressees.

Answer (score 26):

While this is still *technically* true, it should be noted that the behavior of this is not how it used to be.

In the new system, *edits to comments do not reflect in your global inbox*. Edits to comments still reflect in the "responses" report on your profile page. There's still no actual pointing out of this fact, and unless you frequent your own profile page as a means of keeping up to date, it is possible to miss the notice.

So, [Ladybug Killer's answer is still correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/40991#40991) that edited comments will reach addresses, but keep in mind that the people at those addresses may not be alerted that they have new mail, and in extreme cases of bad timing may never run across the mail.

Comment: Ah! I expect this explains most of the missed comments I've found days later. Thanks!

Comment: Why was this changed? If someone comments @me, or on one of my questions/answers, I'd like to be notified of their edits.  I'm hardly going to check my recent comments constantly on the off chance that they've been edited.  Any idea why this was changed?

Comment: **This appears to have changed** as per [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in?noredirect=1#comment624544_197393) editing in the @ seems to send red(1) notifications