# Does editing comments to add "@UserName" send out the notification?

Tags: support, comments, edits, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will edited comments reach addressees?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees)

I often write out comments and forget to add the @UserName portion to them. Typically I would delete the comment and then add it to make sure. Is this necessary or will the edit pick up the user name and send the proper notification?

Comment: At first I was worried it was buried in the depths of the [relevant FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but it turns out that this is asked in a separate question anyway: [Will edited comments reach addressees?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees)

Comment: @Grace - I did a search but my keyword choices must have been way off...

Comment: The answer is yes, if anyone is wondering and is too lazy to follow the links.

Comment: I was, and am. So, thanks, @Ether.