# What are the ramifications of editing a comment with a reply well after the 5 minute window?

Tags: support, moderator-abilities, comment-replies, comment-edits

It has been established that [editing a comment reply will resend it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees). But something I was curious about is, what happens if there's been a rather significant passage of time? This only applies to diamond editing of comments, but in the case of an edit well after the 5 minute window...

1. Does the author of a post still get an envelope ping from any comment on that post by someone else gets edited? Is there a time limit on this sort of thing?
2. Does an @-addressed comment reply still produce an envelope ping for the targetted user? Does it matter whether the address was changed or not?
3. In either case that it does produce a ping, and this is the more prominent question on my mind, does this show up with a new timestamp on the envelope's report, or is it only visible by seeing the timestamp the comment was originally posted?

Comment: Do you mean editing of user comments by diamond moderators? That seems like a rare edge case, and when it happens, I suspect that the original commenter is already aware of it (given that it would only occur in contentious cases). It seems more likely that diamond mods would *delete* such comments, rather than trying to clean them up, in which case there would be no notification AFAIK.

Comment: @Robert Third sentence very explicitly mentions this to be applying to only diamonds. I see a lot of opportunity to edit comments. In addition to what I already do on Gaming, I've also flagged one of my own posts to have an incorrect comment edited. Editing helps a lot when things are fairly nested and you don't want to break the order of things. And deletion does not provide notification (in the same vein that self-deleted comments don't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this from how things are currently... thanks to [Alex B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6180/alex-b) for a request that prompted more research.

Editing outside of the 5 minute window behaves absolutely no differently than editing inside of it. Independently of this, however, the envelope is no longer highlighted from comment replies. So neither the post author nor the target of the reply will receive any feasible notice of this. In the new system, the Global Inbox is also not alerted of edits to comments, so that will also provide no data to either user.

To address the final bullet point, the envelope's report *is* updated, and does it at the timestamp of the original posting. This means that, more likely than not, this will be far enough in the past that the user will not know of such an event occurring.

The general conclusion is that until [a request such as this is implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74691/can-editing-comments-as-moderator-trigger-a-notification), there are no ramifications of editing comments as far as people knowing of it. For edits that people should be aware of, an accompanying secondary comment should be supplied.