# Can editing comments as moderator trigger a notification?

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

As a moderator, I sometimes edit comments to include the @name of someone where it is appropriate.  For example, if I see this:

> comment: I think you should look at tool XYZ. - user1 Mar 20 '10 at 14:32
>
> comment: user1 you should try tool ABC instead of XYZ - user2 Mar 20 '10 at 15:35

Then I'll edit the second comment to say @user1 as in:

> comment: @user1 you should try tool ABC instead of XYZ - user2 Mar 20 '10 at 15:35

I believe this shows better comment etiquette for future users (a signpost) and I had hoped it would notify user1 of the response to their comment, but testing has shown otherwise.

Can a moderator edited comment trigger an "@" notification in the global inbox when appropriate?

Comment: My experience has shown that it does work, just that it notifies from the old timestamp. Which in most cases will be so far late that it won't be noticed. Some time ago I had done some research on this [to address a similar question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62988/what-are-the-ramifications-of-editing-a-comment-with-a-reply-well-after-the-5-min), but the research was prior to the Global Inbox, so I don't know how that interacts. Judging by how editing in chat works, though, I believe it will still notify people.

Comment: @GraceNote We tried a simple test case on Money.se this morning and it didn't notify the poster.

Comment: Did the poster check the envelope for the date of the comment as opposed to just checking the Global Inbox? For example, what you just did now *is not* in my global inbox, but it *is* in my envelope report. I think the same would occur with a moderator edit that is long afterwards.

Comment: @GraceNote - We tested the global inbox, not the envelope report.

Comment: Hah, I'm being very clumsy it seems. I've been treating this whole thing as if it was a support question. As a feature request... I'm kinda down with it. It used to (albeit sideways) work, and quite frankly there's no reason to edit in a comment reply to a post unless you intend for it to send out. The only issue I'd see if when you do edit posts that already have replies, you might not really care to make a notice of it.

Comment: Have to be careful implementing this as it could spam someones box pretty hard if a mod keeps re-editting the comments.