# Comment editing by moderators - include a time-stamp

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, timestamps

I suggest that comment's time-stamp/number of revisions is updated to reflect moderator's changes.

---

Motivation:

1. I had to do a triple-check that I wasn't imagining earlier versions of the comment that was edited after I flagged it. Also, an edit to the tone of the comment removes appropriate context to (the tone of the) comments that follow. At least when there is a time-stamp signifying such a change at a later time, one knows there have been revisions after what followed was written. The site ALREADY keeps a time-stamp of the comment. Why not keep the time-stamp of the latest (super-rare) mod's revision?
2. A user has only 5 minutes to revise a comment (one could still update a time-stamp though a number of revisions could suffice) but a mod can do it days later - so a time-stamp update seems appropriate.

Comment: Better split it to two feature requests, even though neither will likely be done. (Still, your right to ask)

Comment: When a comment is edited, an icon indicating this is already placed to the right of the comment. For example, see the two edited comments below this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74691/135615

Comment: I don't see why this should be implemented. Can you explain why this should be a thing? As Bill says, mods should only be editing comments to remove spam and such, and in such a situation I don't think having the timestamp update is all that important.

Comment: @quar Because I had to do a triple-check that I wasn't imagining earlier versions of the comment that was edited after I flagged it. Also, an edit to the tone of the comment removes appropriate context to (the tone of the) comments that follow. At least when there is a time-stamp signifying such a change *at a later time*, one knows there have been revisions after what followed was written. The site ALREADY keeps a time-stamp of the comment. Why not keep the time-stamp of the latest (super-rare) revision?

Comment: An edited comment is marked as edited. Even where a user edits his own comment, the timestamp is not updated.

Comment: @Andrew The difference is that the user has 5 minutes to revise a comment (no need to update a time-stamp) but a mod can do it days later (when many more comments followed the original).

Comment: You may want to add all your justification comments here into your post. However, if the timestamp is used in ordering the comments [unlikely but possible], then updating the timestamp is going to be less than helpful.

Comment: @Andrew I'd like an explanation for the down-votes as this is my first ever feature-request. Is it a reaction to the substance or presentation? Why would anyone not want to make mod's after-the-fact comment edits to leave at least SOME visible trail?

Comment: There's no way I can explain so many downvotes other than to say that voting on Meta and the per-site Metas indicates agreement with the proposal or disagreement. Most people who expressed a preference don't agree with you. Each has his own reasons, though.

Answer (score 19):

I have no idea how much effort it would take to implement this, but I do have some idea how much utility it would have. Almost none at all. Moderators editing comments should be exceedingly rare. They should only be doing this to remove profanity or spam links from otherwise useful comments. Since useful comments that contain profanity and spam links are so rare, this ability is almost never used. Most comments that moderators process are simply deleted instead.

So, while I'm not *strongly* opposed to this, I don't think it would be used often enough to justify the effort. If a moderator has edited your comment to change its meaning to something other than what you intended, you should flag it for another moderator to review, or bring it up on your Meta site for the community to weigh in on.

Comment: Additional reference - [When should moderators edit comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238095/164200).

Comment: Comments already have a time-stamp. Updating it upon moderator's action should be trivial.

Comment: For another point of reference, when I was a moderator on SO, I probably edited a single digit number of comments that weren't my own, while deleting tens of thousands of them.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, changes to other people's software are always trivial.

Comment: Noted. But if a (rarely used) feature of editing comments by mods (well after they were written) is implemented, shouldn't it be properly implement and leave at least some mark? (such as an updated time-stamp?)

Comment: @A.S. No, because there shouldn't be any indication that something has changed. If a moderator had to edit a comment, it means it had something nasty. Ideally, it should be like that nasty thing never happened.

Comment: @A.S. There is a pencil icon placed at the end of the comment to indicate that it has been edited. Updating the existing timestamp does seem trivial, but keeping a revision of comments probably wouldn't be.

Comment: @Bill I'm not advocating for making a revision history public. Simply knowing that the comment was revised is not enough as the user only has 5 minutes to revise but a mod can do it days later. See my comment in the OP for my motivation.

Answer (score 5):

[This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272339/comment-editing-by-moderators-remove-or-include-time-stamp/272344#comment884068_272341) of Bill the Lizard says it all to me:

> For another point of reference, when I was a moderator on SO, I probably edited a single digit number of comments that weren't my own, while deleting tens of thousands of them.

Okay, so you really want to implement this feature that is only useful in, let's say, 10 times a year on the largest site in the network, Stack Overflow (where Bill was a mod)? That doesn't seem worth the investment to me.

Besides that, I don't see the point. If a moderator decides to edit a comment, it is A) an excellent comment and B) a minor thing to fix. For that, we should trust moderators. They'd easily delete comments, so why would a moderator put in their precious time to edit a comment that isn't worth the change?

Comment: If a (rarely used) feature is already implemented, it should be implement properly. Mods should not do *minor* edits to comments. Minimal - yes. Minor - no. If mod's comment revision (long after the comment was written) is not minor, there should be at least a minimal record of a revision happening, for other comments that followed could lose their proper context.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to have a proper history for comment edits, but this is really rarely a problem if the moderators are careful. Editing comments is pretty rare, and there are very few compelling reasons to do so. Anything involving offensive comments is better handled by deleting them, and edits that fix links or typos generally don't cause any issues.

There are cases where moderators editing comments caused a bit of trouble, but the ones I remember were comments with offensive language that were "toned down" a bit. That just turned out to be a bad idea, and can easily be avoided by just nuking the comments. Anything but trivial edits to comments are problematic and just shouldn't be done by moderators.