# Possible bug in comment @replies with trailing dots

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, notifications

I received a comment to [this answer on tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/counting-tokens/10208#10208), and "@Hendrik." was used to notify me:

[image: Comment with @name reply; no pencil icon indicating any edit]

According to [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020), the trailing dot shouldn't have mattered, and I should have gotten a notification of the comment. Instead, a strange thing happened: I didn't get a "red-dot-notification" in my inbox (in fact, there's still nothing about this comment in my inbox), but when I hit the (non-lit) envelope, I found the reply.

Maybe some recent change to the comment-reply feature caused this?

Comment: (Just a comment to ensure you *do* get Inbox notification in general.)

Comment: @Arjan: How many notifications did you get?

Comment: I assume that the contents of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox are used to populate that list, but just in case it helps investigating: does that URL indeed not show you the item either?

Comment: Ah, I was just looking in my Inbox, so did not *see* a red notification for your 2nd comment. But it is in that Inbox (combined with your 1st comment).

Comment: @Arjan. Nope, not in there.

Comment: Oh, the 3rd notification is there too, so starting with `@User.` works fine for me too.

Comment: Any notification for this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77524/what-would-be-the-criteria-for-rejecting-a-suggested-edit/77532#comment-190274

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77524/what-would-be-the-criteria-for-rejecting-a-suggested-edit/77532#comment-190274) I got a notification. Maybe the reason was that I already had another notification to that question?

Answer (score 2):

**The following is wrong, as [moderator edits *do* show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66386/can-anyone-at-all-edit-my-comments/66387#66387) the little pencil, which is *not* visible in the comment that is being discussed here. Hence: the comment has not been edited!**

---

I guess Joseph edited the comment to fix a typo in your name, and that this happened after the 5 minute edit window. <s>Such edit is not shown using the little pencil [image: Edited comment], due to him being a moderator. (Or maybe another moderator made the edit; maybe point Joseph to this question?)</s>

See also [What are the ramifications of editing a comment with a reply well after the 5 minute window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62988/what-are-the-ramifications-of-editing-a-comment-with-a-reply-well-after-the-5-min):

> [...] the envelope is no longer highlighted from comment replies. So neither the post author nor the target of the reply will receive any feasible notice of this. In the new system, the Global Inbox is also not alerted of edits to comments, so that will also provide no data to either user.

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks, this might be possible. It wouldn't be the first time that Joseph misspelled my name. I did point Joseph to this question already, but I'll also ask him if he remembers an edit, and I'll do some testing myself.

Comment: @Hen. Testing yourself is a bit hard if you're not a moderator: you cannot edit outside of the 5 minute window then...

Comment: @Arjan: Here I was notified, so your answer seems indeed to be the correct one. With "testing myself" I meant leaving comments of the sort of Joseph's comments, and asking the user what happened. I'll wait a bit with accepting your answer.

Comment: It would surely be nice if Joseph (or anyone) can confirm the edit to start with, before accepting, @HendrikV.

Comment: And again I was notified `:-)`

Comment: Seems like @Hendrik's notifications are not any issue at all! ;-)

Comment: Even this worked `:-)` I asked Joseph if he remembers an edit. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Moderator edits do show the pencil

Comment: @Michael: Thanks! @Arjan: Hmm, so maybe it was just some anomaly?

Comment: Okay, @Hendrik, totally forgot about this. Then I guess I cannot delete this answer anymore—or do zero-answer questions not count towards accept rates...? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: The strange this is that [0 up-vote answer seem to count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79189/strange-author-of-community-wiki-post/79586#79586).

Comment: @Arjan: I have unaccepted this answer for testing purposes. Did you get some notification of that as [described in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer/104147#104147)? (I'm actually somewhat hesitant to reaccept your answer afterwards ... `:-)`)

Comment: Nope, @Hendrik. It does say -5 for today, and my profile shows +10 for one upvote I got. But I fail to see where the -15 came from. (Now I can finally delete this answer, later on!)

Comment: @Hendrik, http://i.stack.imgur.com/EBWEl.png for proof ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: Great, thanks. So I'll revert that status-completed from the other question. EDIT: Oh my, I can't!

Comment: (Okay, so I still cannot remove this as you now linked to it! `;-)`)