# Notifications of comments on nominations

Tags: bug, status-completed, nominations

When someone comments on my self-nomination for moderator, I get a notification, but when I click on it, I don't get to it. I wind up somewhere else.

Comment: And comment notifications sometimes don't turn up at all despite  `@username`. (Although that's a different issue)

Comment: @Pekka Edits to comments don't trigger the global inbox to change. Chances are, you didn't receive the notification because it was edited in at a later point. See [my answer to an older question of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees).

Comment: @Grace ah, fair enough! It could have been that.

Comment: @Pekka As a handy tip, your envelope report will still have the comment replies (as noted in said answer). So you can *mostly* confirm this by cross-referencing it with your global inbox and noting how anything absent from the inbox probably has a pencil next to it.

Comment: @Grace ah, thanks! Makes sense.

Comment: Comment notifications are still broken... comments on my nomination are showing up in my inbox, but the title says `User commented on` and then ends - there is no link for what they commented on.

Comment: @nhinkle There is, but the link has no text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comments on nomination posts do not trigger the StackExchange™ SuperCollider MegaDropdown™ and are broken on the envelope page.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77518/comments-on-nomination-posts-do-not-trigger-the-stackexchange-supercollider-mega)

Comment: 77518 is a dupe of this question... the screenshot is nice, though.

Answer (score 2):

You should get properly notified of comments on election nominations now. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: no problem. I got a lot of rep from meta readers voting this up over the months.