# When a comment is edited to include an @lert, does the user get notified?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will edited comments reach addressees?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees)

When I edit a comment to include @SomeonesUsername, does that user get notified?