# If I edit a comment will that generate an inbox message?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will edited comments reach addressees?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees)

If I make a comment to an answer an inbox message will be sent to the author of the answer.

Now if I edit my comment will he receive a new inbox message?