# Should I be mentioning people in separate comments or a unified comment?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, comment-replies

If two people happen to comment on a question or answer, do I have to reply to them in separate comments (as below)

> @ExampleGuy no, I do not have one.

and:

> @ExampleGirl I can do that.

Or should I use a unified comment:

> @ExampleGuy no, I do not have one; @ExampleGirl I can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do two different comments. If you try to do two @mentions in one comment, only one user will be notified.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/238586):

> #### Can I notify more than one person at a time?
>
> No. Comments containing more than one *@name* [are
> blocked](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-user-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings/2615#2615)
> unless they contain a backtick `` ` ``. In the latter case, only the
> first name mentioned using the *@name* syntax will be
> [notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment/35914#35914).
> For example, *@alice `@bob Hi!`* will notify Alice (if she has
> participated in that post), but not Bob.
>
> An exception is the case when the first *@name* either matched nobody,
> or matched the post's author (and thus isn't necessary); in this case,
> the next *@name* will be checked.
>
> #### Can I change who gets notified after the comment is posted?
>
> When editing a comment within its limited editing period, if you
> change or add *@name*, [the notification may or may not reach the new
> recipient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781)
> depending on timing.